# Externalized figures newenvironment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, tikz-external

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library)

I want to externalize some of the TikZ figures of my document. To do so I am using the `\beginpgfgraphicnamed` command, and I would like to embed it in a new environment. Something like:

```
\newenvironment{myPic}[1]{%
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{#1}\begin{tikzpicture}
}{%
\end{tikzpicture}\endpgfgraphicnamed
}%
```

In the end, a basic document `test.tex` would be :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfrealjobname{test}

\newenvironment{myPic}[1]{%
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{#1}\begin{tikzpicture}
}{%
\end{tikzpicture}\endpgfgraphicnamed
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{myPic}{imageTest}
    \fill[color=red] (0,0) circle (10pt); 
\end{myPic}

\end{document}
```

If I do exactly this, I can compile the external image with

```
pdflatex --jobname=imageTest test.tex
```

without any error, but then compiling the actual `test.tex` document with

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

returns:

```
Runaway argument?
\begin {tikzpicture}  \fill [color=red] (0,0) circle (10pt); \end {my\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgf@next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
```

If I do the same thing not using my own environment

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfrealjobname{test}

\begin{document}

\beginpgfgraphicnamed{imageTest}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[color=red] (0,0) circle (10pt); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed

\end{document}
```

then everything works.

Do you see any problem?

Comment: Have you considered using the `external` TikZ library?  It handles this automatically.

Comment: I found a previous thread where you answered, which solved my problem as well! Thanks. Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library

Comment: As that solved your problem, we'll close this as a duplicate.  If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask a new question.