# How can I use the tikz external library in tikzposter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am using tikzposter to make a poster (obviously). I would like to insert a few rather large tikz figures in that poster. This really lengthens the compilation time. Usually (when writing  articles) I get away with this by using the excellent tikz external class. But, if I activate it in my poster I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
 \par \endinput 
! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpic
ture
```

I suspect this is because the whole poster is one giant tikzpicture. Is there a way to activate the tikz external library selectively?

Comment: If it's a pure memory issue (but it doesn't seems to be), try to compile with `lualatex`... Or just render pdfs from tikz image and include them as any pdf image.

Comment: For the error, see [macros - Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library. - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library) ; however in this case you would need to look at the source code and fix the environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can deactivate the export using `\tikzset{external/export=false}` (or probably by means of `\tikzexternalize[export=false]`).

Then you write `\tikzset{external/export=true}` after `\begin{document}`. Or use `\tikzset{external/export next}` right in front of the pictures which need to be exported.

Here is the extract of the reference manual:

> /tikz/external/export next={ boolean (default true)    A boolean which
>   can be used to disable the export mechanism for single pictures.
>
> /tikz/external/export={ boolean }    (no default, initially true)    A
>   boolean which can be used to disable the export mechanism for all
>   pictures inside of the current  TEX-scope.