# pgfplots conflict

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, incompatibility

I am using this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{red eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
        left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
        overlay={\fill[red!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
            (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
            (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
        boxrule=0pt},
    blue eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
        left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
        overlay={\fill[blue!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
            (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
            (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
        boxrule=0pt},
    highlight math style=red eqbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \tcbhighmath{\int x \,e^{-x}\, x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And it produces such an error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.
```

However, if I comment `\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]` or `\tcbset{...}` command, the file compiles correctly.

**Note:** I've created `figures` folder beside my `.tex` file.

Comment: See also (for the general case, not specific to tcolorbox) [macros - Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library. - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if you want to use `externalize` with `tcolorbox`, you need to take special precautions. They are not really specific to `tcolorbox`, an overlay `tikzpicture` generally has the same problem. However, `tcolorbox` has a very nice fix in its `external` library (which you can read about in section **4.23 Externalization** of `tcolorbox` manual v4.30):

```
\tcbset{shield externalize}
```

with which your code becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,external]{tcolorbox}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\tcbset{shield externalize}
\tcbset{red eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
        left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
        overlay={\fill[red!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
            (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
            (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
        boxrule=0pt},
    blue eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
        left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
        overlay={\fill[blue!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
            (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
            (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
        boxrule=0pt},
    highlight math style=red eqbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \tcbhighmath{\int x \,e^{-x}\,\diff x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @antshar Yes. I sometimes think that it might be a good idea if Ti*k*Z could spare all these `overlay` pictures automatically from `externalize`. Similar problems occur e.g. if you combine `externalize` with the `tikzmark` library, which is absolutely not the fault of `tikzmark`.