# Clash between environ and babel (french) packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, babel-french, environ

The explicit code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xmin=1e-1,
    xmax=1e4,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1
  ]
    \draw[thick,blue,dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:100,1);
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works but if I use a new environment, it fails to compile

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,environ}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\NewEnviron{MyEnv}[3][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
      xmin={#2},
      xmax={#3},
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1
    ]
      \BODY
    \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}[]{1e-1}{1e4}
    \draw[thick,blue,dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:100,1);
\end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

The second example compiles correctly if I comment out the `babel` package.

Any ideas on how to fix this? The `shorthandoff` suggestions in answers to other similar questions do not seem to work here.

Comment: why are you grabbing the body instead of using a normal environment?

Comment: I wrote the `bodeplot` package a while ago, and at the time, I could not figure out how to handle the argument macros correctly using the usual `\newenvironment` command. I was able to get it to work using `\newenviron` from the `environ` package.

The functionality I wanted was the ability to pass `tikz` commands and `pgf` keys to environments inside the newly created environment. For example, write something like `\begin{MyEnv}[tikz/{},axes/{}]...`  and pass the `tikz` options to `tikzpicture` and `axes` options to `axis`. I got that to work using `\newenviron.`

Comment: sorry but I can't see what you gain from environ. It makes things only more complicated here as it freezes catcodes.

Comment: There might very well be a way to do what I need without `environ,` unfortunately, I am better at control theory than LaTeX :-) I'll try to rewrite my package again without `environ,` but just wanted to see if anyone has any quick fixes in the meantime...

Comment: I looked through my changelogs. I had to use `environ` to get externalization to work right. I followed [this answer that suggested the `environ` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15614/110602)

Comment: You can disable the shorthand with `\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\shorthandoff{;}}`. Btw: the environ package is no longer needed, a current LaTeX has the functionality in-built. `\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{omm+b}{...}{}`. Use `#4` instead of `\BODY` in the content.

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{O{}mm}{\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin={#2},xmax={#3},ymin=0,ymax=1]}{\end{semilogxaxis}\end{tikzpicture}`, no need to grab the contents.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks! `AddToHook` with `NewDocumentEnvironment` works like a charm. A question if you do not mind. I thought instead of `AddToHook`, I could pass `handle active characters in code` to the `tikzpicture` environment. That did not work, but I do not understand why. Could you help me understand? I tried the `tikz` key so that the user will still be able to use French text inside node labels and such. I assume if I use `AddToHook`, then all semicolons in the entire environment can no longer be modified by `babel`?

Comment: @Skillmon, thanks, but the approach you suggested does not play nice with the `external` library. Using an empty `{}` for the fourth argument and adding the body contents along with the environment end commands to the third argument of `NewDocumentEnvironment`, like @UlrikeFischer suggested, solves issues with externalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

EDIT: A better way to do this is to generate a list of current shorthands and then disable all of them, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708797/110602). Manually disabling shorthands like `;` can lead to errors if `;` is not a shorthand (see comments below).

---

Original answer: As suggested by @UlrikeFischer in the comments,

```
\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\shorthandoff{;}}
```

to handle active characters works. The `environ` package was used to avoid conflicts with the `tikz` `external` library. The `xparse` package can also be used instead of `environ.`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figure]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\shorthandoff{;}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{O{}mm+b}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin={#2},xmax={#3},ymin=0,ymax=1]
            #4
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{MyEnv}[]{1e-1}{1e4}
        \draw[thick,blue,dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:100,1);
    \end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a multilingual document with French and e.g  English, and English being the main language, bodeplot will try to switch handles off: \shorthandoff{;:!?}, even though there are not active. The test \AtBeginDocument{
  \ifdefined\frenchbsetup
only works in a monolingual French document

Comment: Darn. I'll see if I can check whether the characters are active directly, instead of checking whether French language is selected. Does anyone have any other ways this can be achieved?

Comment: That was my thought, too. You would need four checks and that for each function...

Comment: Do you have an example of the failure? I just compiled a test document with `\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}` and it worked fine.

Comment: based on one of your examples: works fine with pdflatex, error with lualalatex, had not realised this before "! Package babel Error: I can't switch '?' on or off--not a shorthand."


 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[pgf]{bodeplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{BodeMagPlot}[height=2cm,width=4cm] {0.01} {100}
\addBodeZPKPlots[%
true/{black,thick},
linear/{red,dashed,thick},
asymptotic/{blue,dotted,thick}]
{magnitude}
{z/{0,{-0.1,-0.5},{-0.1,0.5}},p/{{-0.5,-10},{-0.5,10}},k/10}
\end{BodeMagPlot} 
\end{document}

Comment: I fixed this thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708797/110602) by Javier Bezos, the `babel` maintainer. [Version 1.1.7](https://github.com/rlkamalapurkar/bodeplot/releases/tag/v1.1.7) should work regardless of languages or compilers. I tested your example, and it does fail with `lualatex` in v1.1.6, but compiles fine in v1.1.7.

Comment: thanks to the changes, with Version 1.1.7 also my large document compiles error-free