# How to handle babel active characters when writing a package?

Tags: babel, active-characters

In the `bodeplot` package, I defined new environments using (defined like this to avoid issues with externalization of `tikz` graphics)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xparse}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{O{}mm+b}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin={#2},xmax={#3},ymin=0,ymax=1]
      #4
    \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
```

I want users to be able to use the new environment to do things like this

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{MyEnv}[]{1e-1}{1e4}
    \draw[thick,blue,dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:100,1);
    \addplot[variable=t,domain=1e-1:1e4] gnuplot {(t>100)?0.2:0.5};
  \end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

All of this works out for English language documents. However, if a user uses `babel` with any language that makes some characters in `#4` active, the document cannot be compiled. For example, if I add

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

to the preamble, I get compilation errors.

I managed to make it work for the French language work by checking for `frenchbsetup` and using

```
\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\shorthandoff{;:!?}}
```

if it is detected. However, doing something like this for every active character in every language seems like the wrong approach to solve this issue.

Is there a better way detect and manage active characters in macros like this that will work with all languages supported by `babel`?

Comment: The `b` is functionally similar to the workaround [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15595/110602) to enable externalization. If there is a way to make the `\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{...}{\begin{tikzpicture}...} {...\end{tikzpicture}}` syntax play nice with externalization, I am all for it!

Comment: ok.............

Comment: you can try `\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname`. Or ask the babel maintainer to make the shorthands protected.

Comment: I tried adding `\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname` to the preamble, but the error remains the same. I will try to reach out to the `babel' maintainer.

Comment: your example compiles fine for me with `\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname
` in a current texlive. (But you should set that only locally in your environment).

Comment: I am using a fully updated MikTeX distribution. For me, it works if I use `lualatex` or `xelatex`, but not if I use `pdflatex` or `latex`. Weirdly, this is true with or without `@safe@activestrue`. The error disappears altogether if I use `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: Ok, I isolated the issue. If I load the `babel` library using `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, then I get compilation errors with or without `\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname`. If the library is not loaded, then the compilation errors go away when `\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname` is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure how `tikz` deals with catcodes, but I presume they must be changed somehow to their default values, usually 12 (‘other’). And the only way is with `\shorthandoff` (or with the low level `\catcode`).

However, perhaps the following idea works for you: there is a macro named `\dospecials` storing ‘special’ characters, and `babel` adds shorthands to it. Since they are stored as macros (ie, `;` is stored as `\;`), we need some trick to get the actual character. Then we can use `\ifbabelshorthand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\makeatletter
\let\shorthandlist\@empty
\def\do#1{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1\relax
    \lowercase{\ifbabelshorthand~{\g@addto@macro\shorthandlist{~}}{}}
  \endgroup}
\dospecials
\makeatother

\show\shorthandlist
```

This will show `->~:;!?.`, which, if we remove the characters added by `\show`, is `~:;!?`. It may not work for you, but at least I tried .

EDIT: Once the shorthand list is assembled, it can be used to turn shorthands off in `MyEnv` using `\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\expandafter\shorthandoff\expandafter{\shorthandlist}}`. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xparse}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{O{}mm+b}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin={#2},xmax={#3},ymin=0,ymax=1]
            #4
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{}

\makeatletter
\let\shorthandlist\@empty
\def\do#1{%
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`#1\relax
    \lowercase{\ifbabelshorthand~{\g@addto@macro\shorthandlist{~}}{}}
    \endgroup}
\dospecials
\makeatother
\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\expandafter\shorthandoff\expandafter{\shorthandlist}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{MyEnv}[]{1e-1}{1e4}
        \draw[thick,blue,dashed] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:100,1);
        \addplot[variable=t,domain=1e-1:1e4] gnuplot {(t>100)?0.2:0.5};
    \end{MyEnv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should do for what I have in mind. All I have to do is add the hook `\AddToHook{env/MyEnv/begin}{\expandafter\shorthandoff\expandafter{\shorthandlist}}` and things work out. Thanks! Would you mind if I add the hook to your answer just for completeness?

Comment: @Rushi Not at all. Please, do it! Maybe `babel` should provide such a list is a more manageable way (or even something like `\shorthandoff{all}`).